# Problem with libusbmuxd-2.0.dylib. Trying to access IOS devive properties from python

Tags: python, macos, dylib

I need to access IOS Devices properties connected via usb to computers running Windows or Mac OS. I found a library for python called libusbmuxd. I run

```
pip install libusbmuxd
```

Inside python interpreter:

On Mac OS:

I run:

```
>>> import libusbmuxd
```

and it raises

```
OSError: dlopen(libusbmuxd-2.0.dylib, 6): image not found
```

Any help ?

Answer (score 0):

The PIP package only contains python binding code. You also need to install the library's binary files. Install them with `brew` or MacPorts, e.g. `brew install libusbmuxd`

Comment: My main purpose was to read iPhone devices connected via USB from the computer. I finally found compiled the libimobiledevice library working in both Windows and Mac OS. I'm developing with Python the GUI and implementing the reading with subprocess python library.

Comment: So you have libimobiledevice (with its dependencies like libusbmuxd) installed on your macOS, and still have the issue during dynamic linkage phase? Then `libusbmuxd-2.0.dylib` must be present somewhere in your filesystem. Try to find it `sudo find / -name libusbmuxd\*.dylib` and put the folder in the environment variable DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH: `export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/dylib`. Then run python interpreter.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Finally, I took another approach. But, this comment is very helpful for the next scenarios.